# Why can't I call an interface with a collection of methods from the main package

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, struct, interface

I am really new to golang and I am trying to see how encapsulation really works in go.

I have the following structure

```
-- package a
    -a_core.go
    -a.go
    -models.go

-- main.go
```

In **models.go** I have structs for request and responses for an api call,

**a.go** has an empty struct, which is private and a public interface, which I want to expose with various methods

**a_core.go** just has some business logic which would be called in my interface implementation

Then, I have a **main.go** where I just call the public interface.

**code in a.go**

```
package a

type myFunction struct{}

type MyFunc interface {
 Create(myData *MyData) (*MyData, error)
 Fetch(test string)
 Delete(test string)
}

//Concrete implementations that can be accessed publicly
func (a *myFunction) Create(data *MyData) (*MyData, error) {
  return nil, nil   
}

func (a *myFunction) Fetch(test string) {

}

func (a *myFunction) Delete(test string) {

}
```

In main.go, I call the interface my first create the MyData pointer with values

```
data := &a.MyData{
 /////
}

result, err := a.MyFunc.Create(data)
```

I get the following error when I do this,

too few arguments in call to a.MyFunc.Create

cannot use data (variable of type *a.MyData) as a.MyFunc value in argument to a.MyFunc.Create: missing method CreatecompilerInvalidIfaceAssign

Please what am I doing wrong?

Comment: This [playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/pIyN8NepjOL) might help you understand how interfaces work (the [tour](https://tour.golang.org/methods/9) has further info).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example
Note that names in uppercase are public, in lowercase private (see https://tour.golang.org/basics/3 )

./go-example/main.go

```
package main

import "go-example/animal"

func main() {
    var a animal.Animal
    a = animal.Lion{Age: 10}
    a.Breathe()
    a.Walk()
}
```

./go-example/animal/animal.go

```
package animal

import "fmt"

type Animal interface {
    Breathe()
    Walk()
}

type Lion struct {
    Age int
}

func (l Lion) Breathe() {
    fmt.Println("Lion breathes")
}

func (l Lion) Walk() {
    fmt.Println("Lion walk")
}
```

Comment: I am trying to reference this from a different package. Hence, why I have to do a package.interfacename.methodname and the methods are already implemented on the empty struct myFunction